# Open activity in normal mode AND as dialog

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dialog, android-manifest

I have an activity which i want to open with multiple styles. There shall be a menu option to open it as a normal activity, but also the open to open it as a dialog-styled activity from another activity.

My current "hack": Define a new class by letting it extend the other one and leave it empty. So i have two identically classes with different names where one extends the other.
Is there a better method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set style of activity to `android:style/Theme.Dialog`.
2. Use a [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). It can be embedded in an activity, or shown as a dialog.

Comment: In this case it's solution 2

Comment: Can you give me an example code or link? This DialogFragment thing sounds interresting although i dont know how to code that

Comment: @danijoo There's a tutorial in official blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html